# graph in python from a list of edges

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of edges in a text file:

```
0 1
0 2
0 3
1 637
1 754
1 1319 
1 1350
1 1463
1 1523
2 637
2 754
2 1319
2 1350
2 1463
2 1523
3 499
3 539
3 595
3 637
3 706
3 1128
3 1194
3 1213
3 1319
.. ...
```

I need to turn it into a dictionary like this:

```
graph = { "a" : ["c"],
      "b" : ["c", "e"],
      "c" : ["a", "b", "d", "e"],
      "d" : ["c"],
      "e" : ["c", "b"],
      "f" : []
    }
```

my attempt so far has been:

```
import numpy as np
file_name='/Volumes/City_University/data_mining/Ecoli.txt'
key_column=0

dat=np.genfromtxt(file_name,dtype=str)
d={i:[] for i in np.unique(dat[:,key_column])}

for row in dat:
    for key in d.keys():
        if row[key_column]==key :d[key].append(row[1])

print (d)
```

However, this does not work properly inasmuch i don't get a new key when this appear in the values: as an example
I get:

```
'0': ["1", "2", "3"]
'1': ['637', '754', '1319', '1350', '1463', '1523']
```

in the '1', the "0" is missing.

to make it more simple. If I have a text like this

```
a b
c d
```

I should get an outcome like:
graph = { "a": ["b"], "b": ["a"], "c": ["d"], "d": ["c"]}

thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a bidirectional graph, you need two appends.

Also, you don't really need the `for key in d.keys()` loop, just append to `d[row[0]]` instead of `d[key]`.

```
for row in dat:
    d[row[0]].append(row[1])
    d[row[1]].append(row[0])
```

---

Also, consider using a defaultdict, in which case you wouldn't need to initialize `d` with `np.unique`. It will also guard against errors that would otherwise occur when a node only appears in the second column.

```
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict

file_name='/Volumes/City_University/data_mining/Ecoli.txt'
dat=np.genfromtxt(file_name,dtype=str)
d=defaultdict(list)

for row in dat:
    d[row[0]].append(row[1])
    d[row[1]].append(row[0])

print (d)
```

Comment: the line d[row[1]].append(row[0]) gives me an error (KeyErroe: 754')

Comment: I'm guessing that happens when "754" appears in the second column in your data, but not the first. I think you could do `d={i:[] for i in np.unique(dat[:,0]) + np.unique(dat[:,1])}`, but using a defaultdict would be easier. Edited.